# Issue while using qmlRegisterType in two qml files

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I have a c++ class which is registered as a `qmlRegisterType` in my `main.cpp` as below:

```
qmlRegisterType<MyTestClass>("com.my.MyTestClass", 1, 0, "MyTestClass");
```

I am using this class in two QML files as below:

```
// MyMain.qml 
Window {
  width: 1280
  height: 720

  StackLayout {
     anchors.fill: parent
     currentIndex: 0 
     MyQml1 {} 
     MyQml2 {} 
  }
}

// MyQml1.qml 
Item {

  MyTestClass {
    id: myTestClass1Obj
    onTestSignal: {
       console.log("This function is not getting called");
    }
  }

}

// MyQml2.qml 
Item {

  MyTestClass {
    id: myTestClass2Obj
    onTestSignal: {
       console.log("This function is getting called");
    }
  }
}
```

In above code the function `onTestSignal` from `MyQml2.qml` is getting called but not of `MyQml2.qml`.
If I register MyTestClass as `qmlRegisterSingletonType` then it works with `Connections`.
What is causing the issue?

Comment: How you are triggering the signal? In your case, `MyTestClass` is acting as separate instances. Assume on the click of a button from your main.qml if you want the signal to be emitted, you have to trigger both instances in `MyQml1` & `MyQml2` .

In singleton case to simply say all instances will acts like a global static instance.

Comment: In my class I receive one external event and on that event I am emiting the signal, which I want to receive in the qml file whichever is active in the StackLayout

Comment: why not provide the class code?

Comment: Most probably your external event triggers only one of the `MyTestClass`. For furthur info share the class code.